# Proving that all solutions of $y''+y\cdot\arctan(x)=0$ are bounded

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to show that all solutions of differential equation $$y''+y\cdot \arctan(x)=0$$ are bounded on $x\geq 0$ .

Comment: What do you think should be the approach to the problem? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I have no idea... Maybe I should  transform this equation to system and prove asymptotic stability of zero solution?

Comment: By virtue of being sinusoidal the [solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%E2%80%99%E2%80%99+%2B+y*arctan%28x%29+%3D+0) are bounded

Comment: And how can I show that they are sinusoidal?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Let $z(x) = \frac{1}{\arctan x}(y'(x))^2 + y^2(x)$. Show that $z'\le 0$. Then for $x\ge 1$ we have
$$ |y(x)|\le\sqrt{z(x)}\le\sqrt{z(1)}, $$
so $y$ is bounded from above (say on $x\ge 1$) by $C$, where $C = \sqrt{z(1)}$.